# Magento: Add customer attribute don't set default value for existing customers

Tags: magento

I am creating a customer attribute in which the default value is 1, but after the attribute is created, it not set the attribute default value for existing customers.

This is my installer script

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();
$setup = Mage::getModel('customer/entity_setup', 'core_setup');

$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'is_activated', array(
    'type'          => 'int',
    'input'         => 'select',
    'label'         => 'Activated',
    'global'        => 1,
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'      => 0,
    'user_defined'  => 0,
    'default'       => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 0,
    'source'        => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try :

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


$installer->addAttribute("customer", "is_activated",  array(
    "type"     => "int",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Is Activated",
    "input"    => "select",
    "source"   => "eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "Yes",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""

    ));

        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "is_activated");


$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100)
        ;
        $attribute->save();



$installer->endSetup();
     ?>
```

Also make sure the setup class in resources in config.xml is **Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup**

Answer (score 1):

Thank @Blastfreak, I have tried your way, but it doesn't work for me. So I updated my code to add this code at the bottom of the setup script for manually updating value for the new attribute.

```
function callback($args)
{
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
    $customer->setData($args['row']);
    $customer->setExtraStatus('active');
    $customer->getResource()->saveAttribute($customer, 'extra_status'); // is_validated be change to extra_status
}

$installer->startSetup();

$customers = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_iterator')->walk($customers->getSelect(), array('callback'));

$installer->endSetup();
```